# Update multiple select dropdown(select 2) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, foreign-keys, dropdown

I am creating a product, where i will select multiple categories from multiple select dropdown list. product information will be saved in **product** table

```
Product_Id  Name Description
1001        Abc   Abcdescription
1002        Xyz   Xyzdescription
```

and selected categories will be saved in another table **product_cat_type** by product_Id

```
Type_Id Product_Id  Category    
1       1001        Electronics 
2       1001        Devices     
3       1001        Gadgets
```

now i want to **update** product 1001, all data showing in their respective boxes but multiple select drop down not populating with their previously select categories.

**Controller**

```
 model.prodcategory= new SelectList(db.Product_category.ToList(), "Category_id", "Category_name");
```

**Viewmodel**

```
 [NotMapped]
 public int[] Category_iid { get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> prodcategory{ get; set; }
```

**View Page**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category_iid, Model.prodcategory, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control m-select2", multiple = "multiple", id = "kt_select2_3" })
```

now i am trying to append from product_cat_type **Product_Id** column values to **Category_iid**

**present output**
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwsuQ.jpg)

**expected output**
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROwZD.jpg)

Note: I am doing this by using linq code without using any ajax, jquery or json

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @ZachPedigo Sir, i have updated my code please find.

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest creating the dropdown list in vanilla JS rather than in the HTML. Have you considered giving this approach a shot? Or is there a specific reason you need to use html?

Comment: @ZachPedigo,  I am not that much familiar with JavaScript / Jquery or Vanilla JS, so I am using HTML and facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those people who have shown their interest in my question. while searching more about it, i got another stack overflow question, where i got answer as per my requirement.

**[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013223/asp-net-mvc-multiple-select-dropdown)** to visit the similar question.